# Shell Script for going through a dir recursively and chmodding based on conditions of file type

Tags: bash, command-line, shell-script, zsh

Can anyone point me to either code or a tutorial for writing a shell script that can recursively go through an entire directory structure (starting at the current working directory, or given an required argument of where to start at) and can:

1. Determine whether an item is a directory, and if it is, `chmod 755` it, or...
2. Determine whether an item is a file (not a dir), and `chmod 644` it.

I'm looking for compatibility with Ubuntu, Debian, RHEL-Based, etc., so I'm not tagging this with any particular language.  I'd like this in Bash, but if you have a ZSH script, that will work also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am used to this one-line command (will recurse starting in current working directory)

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 '{}' + -or -type f -exec chmod 0644 '{}' +
```

Explanation:

```
find .                    # starting in curdir find   
-type d                   # any directory
-exec chmod 0755 '{}'     # and chmod it to 755
+                         # (variant of -exec look find man page)
-or                       # or
-type f                   # any file
-exec chmod 0644 '{}'     # and chmod it to 644
+                         # (as above)
```

Comment: That worked.  I take it if I do this in a script, and I set a `cd /path/to/dir/` it will change the working directory, so I can use it as an argument-based command/script?

Comment: I just tested and cd does appear to change the working directory in a script. Not sure if there are any exceptions to that, though.

Comment: @palintropos `cd` does change the working directory in scripts. If that has ever not happened for you, that's quite strange. You might want to post a new question about that ...with details.

Comment: @palitropos in your script you can just pass the topmost directory to find instead of .

Comment: Tiny nitpick: this would be a fully portable solution with `-o` instead of `-or` (a GNUism, same applies to `-and`).

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer:

```
chmod -R a+rX .
```

`+X` (note the capital X) means to give the execute permission if the execute permission was already present for some user. If you have a directory tree which has the right permissions for the owner and you want to make it accessible to everyone, this is the right command to use. It not only makes directories world-executable, but also executable files.

If you also want to reset write permissions to owner only and clear any setuid/setgid bit, make that

```
chmod -R a-ws,u+w,a+rX .
```

The obligatory zsh two-liner, if you don't want to make any file executable:

```
chmod 755 **/*(/)
chmod 644 **/*(.)
```